# switch color (from light to dark gradient and vice versa) inside Linear Gradient React Native

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

I am implementing an UI using Linear Gradient with light gradient background.
I want to make a switch via which i can change the color of Linear Gradient to dark gradient.
any way to do it. I am new in React Native.
Hope i will get my answer soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the current theme and accordingly apply the colors, you can use if ternaries if you need to. Here is the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance).

```
import React from "react";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();

const DARK_COLORS = ["#4c669f", "#3b5998", "#192f6a"];
const LIGHT_COLORS = ["#0077c2", "#00a1ff", "#00c2ff"];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={colorScheme === "light" ? LIGHT_COLORS : DARK_COLORS}
    >
      // Your Content Here
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here I gave a small example of how I would be using this library, but I believe that this will make it clearer for you on how to apply it in your application.

Until later!